# browser shows white page till the response gets from server

Tags: asp.net

In my .net web application, there are many href element for navigate from one page to another page. When I Click the href on the screen, it takes 10 second to load the page during this time, browser shows white page. how to solve this? please help

Comment: What is it exactly, that you are trying to solve? Do you wish to load the page faster? Do you want to show some sort of feedback to the user, while the page is loading. Please be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Asynchronous Page` in order to resolve this problem

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx